# Question for sentence below

Tags: questions

> We will make a purchase with a payment term of 90 days.

It confused me how should I ask question to get this answer. Would it be correct if say sentence below ?

> With how many days of payment term will you make purchase ?

Comment: The first sentence does not sound correct to me. I would say something like, "We will make a purchase with a payment term of 90 days." In this context a "term" is a period of time.

Comment: I corrected it as you said. Would my question be correct for this sentence?

Comment: No, but there are several ways the question could be asked. I might say "How many days will the payment term be for the purchase you are going to make?"

Comment: Is it totally ungrammatical or sounds weird?  Or would it be understood by native speakers?

Comment: Definitely "purchase" should be "a purchase" or "the purchase". Aside from that, it's hard for me to identify any actual grammar rules it might be violating. I think most native speakers would be able to understand it, although maybe not immediately.

Comment: Agree wih @Era, your question is understandable, but not natural.  I think a native speaker would probably say something like "How long a payment term would you like?" or "How many days payment term do you require?"